# Logstash just gives me two logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if
you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin mi
lestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[
0m
←[33mUsing milestone 2 filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin should be stable, but if
you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin mi
lestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[
0m

My configuration :

```
input {
file {
path => [ "e:\mycsvfile.csv" ]
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
filter {
csv {
columns => ["col1","col2"]
source => "csv_data"
separator => ","
}
}

output {
elasticsearch { 
host => localhost
port => 9200
index => test
index_type => test_type
protocol => http
}
stdout { 
codec => rubydebug
}
}
```

My environment: 
Windows 8 
logstash 1.4.2

Question: Has anyone experienced this before? Where do the logstash logs go? Are there known logstash bugs on windows? My experience is that logstash does not do anything.

I tried:

```
logstash.bat agent -f test.conf --verbose
←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if
you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin mi
lestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[
0m
←[33mUsing milestone 2 filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin should be stable, but if
you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin mi
lestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[
0m
←[32mRegistering file input {:path=>["e:/temp.csv"], :level=>:info}←[0m
←[32mNo sincedb_path set, generating one based on the file path {:sincedb_path=>
"C:\Users\gemini/.sincedb_d8e46c18292a898ea0b5b1cd94987f21", :path=>["e:/tem
p.csv"], :level=>:info}←[0m
←[32mPipeline started {:level=>:info}←[0m
←[32mNew Elasticsearch output {:cluster=>nil, :host=>"localhost", :port=>9200, :
embedded=>false, :protocol=>"http", :level=>:info}←[0m
←[32mAutomatic template management enabled {:manage_template=>"true", :level=>:i
nfo}←[0m
←[32mUsing mapping template {:template=>"{ \"template\" : \"logstash-\", \"se
ttings\" : { \"index.refresh_interval\" : \"5s\" }, \"mappings\" : { \"_
default_\" : { \"_all\" : {\"enabled\" : true}, \"dynamic_templates\
" : [ { \"string_fields\" : { \"match\" : \"\", \"m
atch_mapping_type\" : \"string\", \"mapping\" : { \"type\"
: \"string\", \"index\" : \"analyzed\", \"omit_norms\" : true, \"
fields\" : { \"raw\" : {\"type\": \"string\", \"index\" : \"not_
analyzed\", \"ignore_above\" : 256} } } }
} ], \"properties\" : { \"@version\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"in
dex\": \"not_analyzed\" }, \"geoip\" : { \"type\" : \"object\
", \"dynamic\": true, \"path\": \"full\", \"
properties\" : { \"location\" : { \"type\" : \"geo_point\" }
} } } } }}", :level=>:info}←[0m
```

It stays like this for a while and no new index is created in elasticsearch.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: If your file has two data rows, you should get two documents in elasticsearch.   You're going to have to give us more information to work with.

Comment: I've just updated the question to show you the more detailed result. I have two rows of data, first row contains the field names, second row contains one set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
sincedb_path => "NIL"
```

and it worked.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/inputs/file#setting_sincedb_path

> sincedb_path Value type is string There is no default value for this
>   setting. Where to write the since database (keeps track of the current
>   position of monitored log files). Defaults to the value of environment
>   variable "$SINCEDB_PATH" or "$HOME/.sincedb".

I've had several sincedb files generated in my C:\users{user}.

Comment: So, it happened again. Turned out that when I added "NIL", it generated a NIL file in my bin directory, since that's where my configuration file is located. I guess, the right approach would be, deleting the sincedb* generated files if we want to reset logstash. 

In my case, I will be removing sincedb_path => "NIL", and let it default to my $HOME path. Whenever I want to do a reset, I would just delete the sincedb file generated in my $HOME path.

Answer (score 0):

While using CSV as the input data I had to add:

sincedb_path => "NIL" inside the file{} json

Example :

```
input {
file {
    path => [ "C:/csvfilename.txt"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NIL"
}
```

}

and it worked for logstash version 1.4.2